# how do i write a syntax about my case in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I have two transactions namely first ordinary transaction and the second transaction voucher, in the usual transaction the contents of grub items in addition to the voucher and the transaction voucher grub items only voucher.

This my attempt:

```
SELECT A.notransaksi
    ,b.kodeitem
    ,(SELECT C.namaitem
        FROM tbl_item C
        WHERE b.kodeitem = C.kodeitem) AS namaitem
    ,b.harga
    ,b.potongan
    ,b.total
    ,A.kodesupel
    ,d.kodegrup
FROM tbl_ikhd A
INNER JOIN tbl_ikdt b ON A.notransaksi = b.notransaksi
LEFT JOIN tbl_itempotongan d ON b.kodeitem = d.kodeitem
INNER JOIN tbl_item i ON b.kodeitem = i.kodeitem
INNER JOIN group_posting gp ON gp.kode_group = i.jenis
    AND gp.konsinyasi = i.konsinyasi
WHERE CASE 
        WHEN A.kodesupel = 'VOUCHER'
            THEN A.kodesupel = 'VOUCHER'
                AND d.kodegrup = 'VOUCHER'
        ELSE A.kodesupel = 'UMUM'
        END
    AND SUBSTR(A.keterangan, 1, 3) = ''
    AND A.shiftkerja = 'PAGI'
    AND to_char(A.tanggal, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = '2018-02-19'
    AND gp.
GROUP = 'PPN'
```

Comment: And  what is your question?  It is not obvious at all.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. It will help you to write questions easier to answer.